# How to Setup OnGoing Notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am trying to setup a status bar notification with more than 3 intent actions, but the maximum intent actions I can get is ONLY 3:

```
    .addAction(R.drawable.btn_previous, "Prev", pendingIntent_Prev_Song)
    .addAction(R.drawable.btn_next, "Next", pendingIntent_Next_Song)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "To App", BackToApp_PendingIntent)
```

It doesn't matter how many more intent actions I add, it still only shows up 3 in the status bar.
 I know that OnGoing notification may be my solution, but I can't find a way to do so without rewriting my whole code.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you and thank you

Here is my code:

```
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);          
        NotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);                 

        //Back to App Pending Intent
        Intent Notification_Intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        BackToApp_PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, Notification_Intent, 0);       

        //set up notification actions
        Intent Prev_Song = new Intent(PREV_SONG);
        pendingIntent_Prev_Song = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Prev_Song, 0);

        Intent Next_Song = new Intent(NEXT_SONG);
        pendingIntent_Next_Song = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Next_Song, 0);                

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(PREV_SONG);
        intentFilter.addAction(NEXT_SONG);

        .....

        .... 


    public void DisplayMusicStatusBar() {               
            StatusBarNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_button)
//          .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_play))
            .addAction(R.drawable.btn_previous, "Prev", pendingIntent_Prev_Song)
            .addAction(R.drawable.btn_next, "Next", pendingIntent_Next_Song)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "To App", BackToApp_PendingIntent)           
            .setContentText(SongsList.get(SongIndex).get("songTitle"))          
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
//          .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContent(notificationView).build();                  
            NotificationManager.notify(MUSIC_STATUSBAR_ID, StatusBarNotification);
        }
```

Comment: to do like this and change your code, notificationManager.notify(Unique_Integer_Number, notification);

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
        String keys, String msgId, String branchId) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Share - " + keys)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500).setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("Notification from smartshare")
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
            .setSound(alarmSound);
    String consumerid = null;
    Integer position = null;
    Intent resultIntent = null;
    if (consumerid != null) {
        if (msgId != null && !msgId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            if (key != null && key.equalsIgnoreCase("Yo! Matter")) {
                ViewYoDataBase db_yo = new ViewYoDataBase(context);
                position = db_yo.getPosition(msgId);
                if (position != null) {
                    resultIntent = new Intent(context,
                            YoDetailActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("id", Integer.parseInt(msgId));
                    resultIntent.putExtra("position", position);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("notRefresh", "notRefresh");
                } else {
                    resultIntent = new Intent(context,
                            FragmentChangeActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra(key, key);
                }
            } else if (key != null && key.equalsIgnoreCase("Message")) {
                resultIntent = new Intent(context,
                        FragmentChangeActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra(key, key);
            }.
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
} else {
            resultIntent = new Intent(context, FragmentChangeActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra(key, key);
        }
    } else {
        resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainLoginSignUpActivity.class);
    }
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            notify_no, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (notify_no < 9) {
        notify_no = notify_no + 1;
    } else {
        notify_no = 0;
    }
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nNotifyMgr.notify(notify_no + 2, nBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it is nice to show the message notification, but it didn't really answer to my question though. I'm looking for a solution that I can show 4 intent actions such as Prev_song, Play, , Pause, Next_song, progress bar in one notification or ongoing. I can skip song, pause, etc. from the notification. Thanks